# Primary Key and Foreign Key is same when execute at the same time

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

[image: This my stored procedured]

I want show in the column ClubDocumentID: D58ED6B5-0043-4B62-BD1F-7C74221835C3 are same to table ClubDocument which is ClubDocumentID: D58ED6B5-0043-4B62-BD1F-7C74221835C3 same output. But the expected result shows ClubDocumentID:  D58ED6B5-0043-4B62-BD1F-7C74221835C3, able ClubDocument which is ClubDocumentID:  CD8D6BA9-B208-4811-A3CC-1A4484E9FCE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Newid() which generate new GUID every time when you will execute.

You should store NewID() result in a variable and then used that variable to store the result in your tables (primary and secondary).

```
declare @ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
set  @ID =  newid()
```

Comment: if this helps, you can upvote and/or accept the solution.

Comment: How to do that? sorry new also in stackoverflow.